# When to NodeJS Expressjs mounting other app or require other app

Tags: node.js, express

I know it is possible and I experimented that But I'm curious to know some scenario where to require another app and some benefit from that.

Right now for separating task or heavy task I'm forking another process by `cluster` and it's okay for me.

Do you have any experience where you require another app and took that advantage?

Comment: Do you mean require(<filename>)?

Comment: Nope, I'm asking about to start another app from express on which scenario people use that feature.